# Ajax call to php not working - no response on button click

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am having the below ajax call to php which is not working.

```
  var data = ['test1','test2'];
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function() {        

        $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",
            url: "getResult.php",
            data: {testData : data },
            success: function(data) { 
                alert("Data: " + data);
            } 
        });      
    return false; 
    });  
  });
```

PHP side -

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST['testData'];
echo $myArray;
```

Requesting expects to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    $myArray = $_POST['testData'];
```

Comment: I tried $myArray = $_POST['testData']; and still not working. I guess the request is not being received or rather not sent!

Comment: Is the alert being triggered at all?

Comment: No, the alert is not being triggered at all.

Comment: trying changing data to "data: { testData : 'StringTest' },". See if it fires back the alert.

Comment: changed data to "data: { testData : 'StringTest' },". Still alert is not triggered. Is there any way to check server error here?

Comment: ohh, it was my mistake - I have the button identifier as .button which was suppose to be "button". Thanks buddy.